# AngularJs find link by rel attribute is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, attributes, document

If I try this:

```
$document.find('link')
```

It lists this:

```
JQLite(9) [link, link, link, link, link, link, link, link, link]
```

But if I try this:

```
$document.find('link[rel="canonical"]')
```

or

```
$document.find('link[rel="stylesheet"]')
```

or any other `link` present on the page, I get this:

```
JQLite {}
```

and I don't know why and my head is about to explode because I tried all sorts of staff with no success. Basically I try to update the canonical tag if it exists.

Comment: Without seeing the associated HTML or an example which reproduces this problem we can't really help you

Comment: So what you want to say is that this approach should work in a normal context? ..because this is mainly what I do. It's a class who receives $document in the constructor, pass it out to this.$document = $document; and in a method I do something like: const link = this.$document.find('link[rel="canonical"]'); console.log(link). Nothing more, nothing less. If I don't add the [rel="canonical"] it displays a list of links and if I add it I don't get any result.

Comment: `document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')`

Comment: `So what you want to say is that this approach should work in a normal context?` That's right. There's no outward reason that what you have would not work - assuming that `$document` is a reference to an element which contains the element(s) you want to find

Comment: @Spooner I tried that in the first place and it works, but I have specifications to use $document instead of document :(

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks, this is bad news I guess because I don't seem to figure it out why it acts like this..I was hoping that I did something wrong.

Comment: `$document` is just a lite jQuery wrapper for `window.document`, if you try `$document[0].querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]')` that should work.

Comment: Yes, it works like that. I guess I will keep it like this for now because I can't find any other solution at this moment but I hope I will get an answer to my question why it does not works like I did in my example. Thanks

Comment: Great, I've added this as an answer below. Please mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: I gave you thumbs up for the effort but your answer does not answer to my question. Why my approach is not working, your answer is an alternative solution but it's not a definitive one, only until I find the answer the the question and make it work my way. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`$document` is just a lite jQuery wrapper for `window.document`, try:

`$document[0].querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]');`